# Multicurl returns null without any errors (multicurl used more than once)

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to perform multicurl request and keep information about data sent (by GET). I've got array '$params' that contain params I want to send in multiple curls:

```
$m_curl  = curl_multi_init();

// Firstly I create CURL handles
for ($i = 0; $i < count($params); ++$i) {
    $params[$i]['curl'] = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($params[$i]['curl'], CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($params[$i]['curl'], CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($params[$i]['curl'], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($params[$i]['curl'], CURLOPT_URL, $params[$i]['url']);
    curl_multi_add_handle($m_curl, $params[$i]['curl']);
}

// Now we do the multicurl thing
$active = null;
do {
    $status = curl_multi_exec($m_curl, $active);
    if ($status > 0) die ('ERROR!'); // This is not stopping script, so I suppose that we got no errors in requests
} while ($status == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

// Organize response
for ($i = 0; $i < count($params); ++$i) {
    $results[$i] = ['results' => []];

    foreach ($params[$i]['curl'] as $curl) {
        $result        = curl_multi_getcontent($curl);
        $header_size   = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $result_header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
        $result_body   = substr($result, $header_size);

        // We got wrong result - response is NULL
        if ($result == NULL) {
           echo 'empty response!'; // and there should be something
        }
        else {
           // it's OK, co we do stuff there
           // ...
           curl_multi_remove_handle($m_curl, $curl);
        }
    }
}

// Close multicurl
curl_multi_close($m_curl);
```

With such code I've got:
- no CURL errors (status is all the time 0)
- sometimes result is OK and we got response text, sometimes not (and than we got no body, nor head to debug)

The last thing - if I will browse URLs that are empty in muticurl (or send regular CURL), response is correct. There is just no pattern I can follow, so maybe someone can point what I'm doing wrong or what I forgot to do? =/

**Solved:** actually the problem wasn't what I expected could be. I used one time multicurl, add handles, execute them and remove. After that I add other handles and after executing they were getting empty results (but request to server was send).
When I close and reopen multicurl each time I'm putting new data portion the problem was solved.
Sorry for asking wrong question =/

Hope it will help if someone will got same problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    <?php

$params = [
  ['curl' => null, 'url' => "http://google.com"],
  ['curl' => null, 'url' => "http://google.com"],
];

$m_curl  = curl_multi_init();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($params); ++$i) {
    $params[$i]['curl'] = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($params[$i]['curl'], CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($params[$i]['curl'], CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($params[$i]['curl'], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($params[$i]['curl'], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($params[$i]['curl'], CURLOPT_URL, $params[$i]['url']);
    curl_multi_add_handle($m_curl, $params[$i]['curl']);
}

$active = null;
do {
    $status = curl_multi_exec($m_curl, $active);
    if ($status > 0) die ('ERROR!');
} while ($status == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $status == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($m_curl) != -1) {
        do {
            $status = curl_multi_exec($m_curl, $active);
        } while ($status == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}

$result = [];
foreach ($params as $param) {
    $curl_result = curl_multi_getcontent($param['curl']);
    $header_size  = curl_getinfo($param['curl'], CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $result[] = [
        "header" => substr($curl_result, 0, $header_size),
        "body" => substr($curl_result, $header_size)
    ];

    curl_multi_remove_handle($m_curl, $param['curl']);
}

curl_multi_close($m_curl);

var_dump($result);
```